# Information from multiple tables in one foreach loop. Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8, laravel-blade

i am on my view trying to make a table passing a foreach loop which has to pick related data from two separate Tables.

Actual situation, Making a loan managment web app, i have to show to the lender data of the bids he has placed to borrowers but for the table of display to be complete it needs information from two different tables in databases, what do i do

my controller responsible
**loansController**

```
function beggers()
{
    // obtaining loop from different sources
    $user = auth()->user();
    $user_id = ($user->id);/* this calls for data of logged in user */

    $ubids = Bid::select('loan_id')->where('user_id',$user_id);
    $userbids = Loan_requests::where('id',$ubids)->get();
    
    $beg = Loan_requests::all(); 
    return view('beggers',['beg'=>$beg,'userbids'=>$userbids]);


}
```

The view page with the foreach loop
**beggers.blade.php**

```
<h2>Deals Interested in</h2>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Loan Id</td>
        <td>Begger</td> //this is the users name
        <td>Loan Type</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>View More</td>
        <td>status</td>
    </tr>

    @foreach ($userbids as $userbids)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $userbids['id'] }}</td>
        <td>..</td>
        <td>{{ $userbids['LoanType'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $userbids['amount'] }}</td>
        <td>..</td>
        <td>..</td>
    </tr>   
    @endforeach 
</table>
```

Tables responsible
**loan_request**

```
Schema::create('loan_request', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('users_id');
            $table->integer('LoanType');
            $table->Biginteger('amount');
            $table->string('PayType');
            $table->integer('IntervalPay');
            $table->string('GracePeriod');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('users_id')
            ->references('id')->on('users')->ondelete('cascade');
        });
```

and the
**users**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->boolean('role')->nullable( );
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

So what i do want on the loop is be able to call the actual users name who is the begger into the table.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using the same collection as variable

```
 @foreach ($userbids as $userbids)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $userbids['id'] }}</td>
        <td>..</td>
        <td>{{ $userbids['LoanType'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $userbids['amount'] }}</td>
        <td>..</td>
        <td>..</td>
    </tr>   
    @endforeach
```

In this code see the `@foreach($userbids as $userbids)`  you are using the same name .Just change the code like this

```
@foreach ($userbids as $userbid)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $userbid->id }}</td>
            <td>..</td>
            <td>{{ $userbid->LoanType }}</td>
            <td>{{ $userbid->amount }}</td>
            <td>..</td>
            <td>..</td>
        </tr>   
        @endforeach
```

Also laravel get() function return a collection not an array in case you want to change it to an array then

```
$userbids = Loan_requests::where('id',$ubids)->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: i do get an error performing that,

Comment: i do get an error performing that,